# postgresql psycopg2 search in russian not working

Tags: python, postgresql, centos, psycopg2

have a values in DB like this:
`C:\555\Новый текстовый документ.txt`

Have a statement in python bottle script:
`cursor.execute("""select * from main where filename ilike '%%' || %s || '%%' escape ''""", (filename,))`

If i do search by file extension or just numbers its OK. But if i search by russian letters. It show nothing.

P.S. i create DB in ru_RU.UTF8 collaction and have `conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')` in script.
What i am doing wrong?
thank you!

UPDATE 1:
 Here is a code. Also i tested in Adminer, PyAdmin and psql. in them this query is ok. but not in code :(

```
@post('/search')
def search():
        username = request.forms.get('user')
        filename = request.forms.get('file')
        time = request.forms.get('time')
        server = request.forms.get('server')
 if filename:
                cursor.execute("""select * from main where filename ilike  '%%' || %s || '%%' escape ''""", (filename,))
                return template('index', cursor2=cursor)
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you show how you're setting the `filename` variable that gets passed into the execute statement?

Comment: i updated the post. may be the problem on colocation? i changed the colocation of db to ru_RU.UTF8. but no chance :(

Comment: Aha! you was right! i wrote a print(filename) and saw this: "GET /pure-min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Ð½Ð¾Ð² . But how to fix it. prepare and encode this as UTF8? anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is to change code to (instead of filename = request.forms.get):

```
        username = request.forms.user
        filename = request.forms.file
        time = request.forms.time
        server = request.forms.server
```